# ¿Como debo gestionar las conexiones de usuarios desde una aplicación web .net a la base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2008

**Mi pregunta nace en el contexto del desarrollo de una aplicación escrita en C# utilizando .Net MVC4. que se conecte a una base de datos SQL Server 2016**

He visto que normalmente las aplicaciones se configuran en el archivo web.config para gestionar la conexión a la base de datos. En este escenario clásico sólo una cuenta de base de datos es la que se conecta de manera concurrente independiente de la cantidad de usuarios que utilicen la aplicación. Es decir, si 100 usuarios estan conectados a la aplicación .Net, con nombres de usuarios distintos, y reviso las conexiones de SQL Server veré 100 conexiones con el mismo login de base de datos configurado en el web.config.

Me nacen muchas dudas con respecto a esto:

¿Es la forma correcta de manejar las conexiones cuando sólo una cuenta se conecta de forma concurrente a la base de datos desde .Net?

Si existe una forma de que por cada usuario de la aplicación se genere un nuevo login de base de datos y así manejar auditorias específicas de conexión, manejo de datos, etc ¿Cómo se logra en un desarrollo a gran escala?

Gracias de antemano a los expertos que se darán un tiempo para resolver estas dudas.

Comment: Para este caso el usuario conectado a la  BD es la aplicacion, la gestion de ese usuario es el administrador de base de datos, si quieres guardar que hace cada persona implenetas un log y guardas el historial de ejecuciones por usuario.

Comment: Eso quieres decir que existe una conexión del usuario administrador y luego otro conexión por usuario conectado?

Comment: Una base de datos puede ser usada por una o mas aplicaciones, se crean usuarios en BD con ciertos permisos ejemplo si solo lees datos te sirve para reportes, imaginate administrar los permisos de la BD desde una aplicacion creando un nuevo usuario en BD para cada nueva persona, es impractico.